# How to Handle Exception of wrong data type input but the variable was not an object in Java

Tags: java

I had tried doing this for 4 hours, but I still can get it.
How can i handle this input?
I tried to use `instanceof` but is not a object.
when I input non int stuff, it thinks I am inputting zero.

```
if (input was not int or other datatype or even null ){
    System.out.println("Integer please!"); 
}
```

full code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class InputParsing{
    static int [] a = {80, 60, 72, 85, 90};
    static String input;
    static String output;
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void parseInput(){
        int num = 0;
        double total = 0;
        double average = 0;

        output = "The 5 marks are:";
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++){ 
            output += " "+a[i];
        }
        output += "\nAverage of how many numbers? ";

        System.out.print(output);
        input = sc.nextLine();
        try{
            System.out.println("Input length = " + input.length());
            num = Integer.parseInt(input);
            if(num <= 0){
                throw new ArithmeticException();
            }
            total = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<num; i++) 
                total += a[i];
            average = total / num;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            if (input was not int){
                System.out.println("Integer please!"); 
            }
            else if(num > 0){
                System.out.println("Not more than 5 please!");
            }
            else if(num < 0){
                System.out.println("No negative number please!");  
            }
            else if(num == 0){
                System.out.println("Don't input zero!");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Something wrong!");
            }

            throw new ArithmeticException();
        }
        finally{
            System.out.println("Number = " + num);
        }
        System.out.println("Average over first " + num + 
                           " numbers = " + average);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        boolean done = false;
        do{
            try{
                parseInput();
                done = true;
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Number should be 1 to 5!");
            }finally{
                System.out.println();
            }
        }while (! done);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt` will throw a `NumberFormatException`. Catch it, this is your case for `"Integer please!"`.

Answer (score -1):

Can you not just check if the input string is in the integer range you want before you invoke Integer.parseInt() upon it?

i.e.

```
if (char >= '1' && char <= '5') {
    num = Integer.parseInt(char);
}
```

Comment: because is a lab from school so that some code i didn't know why it had to be like that. because some code was given.

Comment: The variable `input` is of type `String` (otherwise the parse call to `Integer.parseInt(input)` would not make much sense). Such a variable cannot be compared to integer values.

Comment: Made an error with my code, I meant to compare a char to an alpha representation of an integer